# Transforming a base class into one of its derived classes?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Is there a shortcut to take a base class and transform it into one of its derived classes inside of a program? For example:

Let's say I have three classes, a base class and two derived classes:

```
class cColor {
};

class cBlue : public cColor {
};

class cRed : public cColor {
};
```

and then I create a Color class inside of my program:

```
int main(){
cColor unsaturated
return 0;
}
```

Is there someway to transform `unsaturated` from a cColor class to a cBlue or cRed class? Would a similar solution be to store `unsaturated` in a pointer, create a new cBlue or cRed class from the pointer and then delete `unsaturated`?

Comment: What does "transform" mean in your mind? The answer is "no", but I'm entirely convinced that you're not thinking about your problem in the right way and that you won't actually *want* any such thing.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Well, I wanted to implement a base object into my program but have it be able to change dynamically according to user input. It really makes no difference working with a simple class but I believe it would become a problem when dealing with extensive and/or detailed classes

Comment: No such thing is possible in C++. An object lives, and then it dies. It is always of one fixed type. There's no such thing as "mutating types". However, this isn't necessary: Typically you first figure our what sort of object you want, and then you create the correct object. You can have an intermediate dispatcher item that holds relevant information until the object is constructed, but there's no need to "overwrite" an existing object.

Comment: @KerrekSB I appreciate your help, I can think of different ways to implement what I was asking, but the real question was whether or not there was a predefined, simpler way of handling it. Obviously everyone is telling me that changing an object would be potentially disastrous or hazardous so that answers my question right there. Thanks for trying to delve deeper though :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the type of an object after it was created (with the exception of construction and destruction, where the derived class object temporarily turns into a base class object). Since derived class objects can be larger than their base classes, there's also no way this could ever work.

The workaround of creating a new derived object, resetting the pointer and then destroying the base object works if there's no one else holding another pointer to the base class. If there's any other pointer or reference to the original object, it will be dangling afterwards. But if you are in control of the only pointer/reference to the class (e.g. if you only access it through a singleton proxy object which never leaks a pointer or reference to the real object) then this method works.

Comment: Alright, thanks for answering my question. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I disagree about "there's also no way this could ever work" in the sense that it is possible to implement in c++ if the standard changed to allow you (even with manual memory management). All the compiler needs to do is allocate room for the largest possible instance :)zzz. +1.

Comment: @trinithis: And how is the compiler supposed to know what the size of the largest possible instance (which might be defined in another translation unit which is not yet written at the time of compiling this one) is?

Comment: @trinithis: What about dynamic libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little rusty in C++, but I believe you are correct.  You will need to use a pointer if you want to declare a variable as cColor, and assign a cBlue or cRed instance to it.

```
cColor* unsaturated = new cBlue();
```

Comment: You can also use a reference - but it must always be initialized. cRed red; cColor &ref=red;

Comment: This is what I anticipated, however, I'm still interested in knowing if there's a way to specifically transform/mutate/morph the base class into a derived class without creating a new instance of the derived classes

Answer (score 0):

You can do a reinterpret_cast, but, going from a base class to another class is seriously unsafe because data members of the target class which do not exist in the source class will not be initialized to anything.

Generally you might use copy constructors to solve situations like this. For example...

```
class cColor 
{ 
   cColor( ColorData );
   ColorData getData();
}; 

class cBlue : public cColor { 
}; 

class cRed : public cColor { 
};
```

Then...

```
int main(){     
ColorData foo;
cColor unsaturated(foo);
rColor rcol(unsaturated.GetData());
return 0;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not looking for a way to 'get around' doing this though, I simply wanted to know if there IS a way and judging from the replies I've received, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use the State pattern from GoF page 305, what you are proposing is very dangerous casting an instance of a base object to a derived class that it is not.  Admittely you might get away with your simple example, but that will fall apart as soon as a derived class adds some state, or alters the vtable.
[http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1321058151&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)